# Swift detect changes UILabel from Array

Tags: swift, uilabel, observer-pattern

I need to detect changes to my `UILabel`. In my code i have in array which is getting updated via `Socket IO`. But the changes only appear when i scroll. I need that when the array changes, the label get updated directly. 
How can i get this working?

in **cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
 cell.currentPrice.text =   String(self.currentPriceArray[indexPath.row]) // and this array get updated via Socket IO
```

In my viewDidLoad i have something like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {


    socket.connect()
    getVeilingen(offset,limit:limit) // method thay updates the array
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I need an observer for this, but with the code what i found i cannot figure it out..
For example, this doesn't solve my problem  (Overriding the UILabel, it give's me weird errors)

```
override var text: String? {
    didSet {
        if let text = text {
            println("Text changed.")
        } else {
            println("Text not changed.")
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: After changing the data source array just call `tableView.reloadData()` to update the view

Comment: thanks! works, perhaps i was thinking to difficult about easy things :)